# South not recognizing added model field?

Tags: django, django-models, migration, django-south, schema-migration

My teammate and I have been using South for a little bit now with very minimal problems. We now just hit an issue where South isn't recognizing our added model field.

When I run

```
./manage.py schemamigration appname --auto
```

I keep getting "Nothing seems to have changed."

Miscellaneous yet random details: 
South==0.8.2 
I checked the db tables and the column is indeed not there.

Update #1: We created our own migration file to add it and it worked. We're just trying to figure out why using schemamigration didn't so we don't have to keep doing it manually..

Update #2: I have a feeling it might have to do with the fieldtype we're using..? I tried adding a charfield and south worked but when it comes to URL field there's no recognition whatsoever...

Answer: I found out what was wrong. Teammate was using a variable name that was also a method name. Can't answer my own question yet because I don't have enough rep but I will when I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what was wrong: my teammate was using a variable name that was also a method name.